# Angular: Resetting Factory or Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, factory

I have a factory in angular that is a complex object and looks something like this:

```
app.factory("mainFcty", function(){
    return {
        a:"",
        b:"",
        c:""
    }
});
```

As the user to continues the process from the app, they fill out the above form. For example say they are making a booking.
They get to the end of the process, add this to a shopping cart and begin the process of filling out the `mainFcty` again.
The problem is when they add the `mainFcty` to the shopping cart, which is an array I need reset the `mainFcty` back to it original state of `a`, `b` and `c` all being empty strings.
For some reason once I have started the process again the app resets it to the original state, but somewhere in the process the bindings to the old `mainFcty` re-appear and overwrite all the data I have collected the second time around.

Anyone have any solid ideas of how to reset the bindings and remove all traces of the old one before continuing the process?

Help is gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Can you make a local object in the closure?  app.factory("mainFcty", [function() { var default_values = { a:"", b:"", c:""}; var current_data = { resetData: function() { $.extend( current_data, default_values ); } }; current_data.resetData(); return current_data; }]);

Comment: That looks like it would work, but which value within the mainFcty would i write the data too and how would i do it? Currently i write to the mainFcty like this:-
mainFcty.a = "HelloWorld";
would it be something like:-
mainFcty.currentData.a = "helloWorld";

Thanks for you help so far :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a default values object, and copy the values to the returnable factory object with a method to overwrite the current values with default values.

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/xmtkg5tz/1/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory("mainFcty", [function() { 
    var current_data = {}; 
    var default_values = { 
        a:"", 
        b:"I am a default that is not-empty", 
        c:"",
        resetData: function() { 
            console.log( 'Resetting')
            return current_data = angular.extend( current_data, default_values ); 
       } 
    }; 
    default_values.resetData();
    return current_data;
}])
.controller('exampleCtrl',['$scope', 'mainFcty', function($scope,mainFcty) {
    $scope.fcty = mainFcty;
    $scope.submit = function() { 
        console.log( 'reset?', $scope.fcty.a, $scope.fcty.b, $scope.fcty.c ); 
        console.log( 'Before:', mainFcty );
        mainFcty.resetData(); 
        console.log( 'After:', mainFcty ); 
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Ah thats awesome, will try and do that now.

Comment: That works fine, apart from one small thing, I have an array with the mainFcty. This is called allTxn, this doesn't seem to reset? Both the default values and the current data are both updating
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle as an example?

Comment: i sorted it thanks, i needed to use copy instead of extend, as it needed to be a deep copy! Thanks for all your help, your a hero! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found it more easy to declare the variable at start of the factory, call reset, and then use reset whenever I want to reset the variable.

```
  .factory('sharedDataUserFlowService', function () {
        var serviceVariables;
        resetData();
        return {
            resetData: resetData,
            triggerFormCheck: triggerFormCheck,

        };

        function resetData() {
             serviceVariables = {
                 triggerFormValidateCheck: false,
                 triggerBlockStageVariable: null,
                 isFormValid: false,
                 blockedStage: null,
                 isProcessEnd: false
             }
        }

        function triggerFormCheck() {
            serviceVariables.triggerFormValidateCheck = !serviceVariables.triggerFormValidateCheck;
        }
```

can be called from anywhere it is injected with `sharedDataUserFlowService.resetData();`

good luck.